# org-mode - Using tasks to automatically generate a weekly dinner menu

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have lots of trouble getting my meals done efficiently and I came up with an idea to try to make it better with Emacs Org-Mode.

I would like to have a task every Friday that repeated itself with .+1w (every seven days after you finish the task) that built my shopping list and looked like the following:

```
*TODO Shopping list
SCHEDULED: <2020-01-05 Fri .+1w>
12 eggs (Spanish omelet)
1 olive oil (spanish omelet)
Pasta (Spaghetti bolognese)
...
```

Of course, we need to have some file called Recipes.org that contained the list of ingredients for our daily meals and that looked like the following:

```
*Spaghetti bolognese
**Pasta
**Tomato sauce
*Spanish omelet
**Eggs
...
```

The content for the shopping list description must be generated automatically every week with some script that randomly picks seven recipes for these week dinners and concatenates all needed ingredients into our shopping list.

Is this already implemented in org-mode? Does anyone know how it may be implemented if it is not?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

While there is no specific 'random-recipe shopping-list generator' built in (that I know of), org-mode provides many different ways to organise this kind of information.

In general implementing your idea with a bit of elisp shouldn't be too difficult - once you have lists of ingredients for each recipe, you could sort and dedupe  before turning them into [checkbox lists](https://orgmode.org/manual/Checkboxes.html#Checkboxes).

You'd then write something up for the random weekly selections. In the end most of the work will be in compiling the recipes and ingredients into org format.

A quick search shows there is at least one existing package for creating shopping lists from recipes: [shopping-lisp.el](https://github.com/metapieman/shopping-lisp). Again, you'd need to translate a bunch of recipes into s-expressions and add the random choice element in elisp.

Here's a [fun post from Sacha Chua](https://sachachua.com/blog/2012/06/emacs-org-grocery-lists-batch-cooking/) on using org-mode and org-tables for tracking recipes and ingredients. Her blog is a great resource for emacs ideas.

Finally, let me just say that I love emacs, and use org-mode daily for checklists, calendars and generally organising my life.

Sometimes though, despite the temptation to do *everything* in org-mode, we have to concede that there may be better, purpose built tools out there for such things that might save us a lot of time and effort... for example the myriad of cooking websites and apps that come ready with recipes, shopping list functions, standardised measures, etc.

Then again, sometimes it's just more fun to build your own.